# Stop knitr compilation button hidden in RStudio Compile PDF window

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr

I just downloaded RStudio 1.0.143 for Windows 7 and am compiling a knitr document. However, in the "Compile PDF" tab the STOP button does not appear when compiling nor the "View Log", "Output", or "Issues" buttons that allow you to troubleshoot a .Rnw file that does not compile. Is there a setting to show these? I have attached an image, they are at the right hand side of the "Compile PDF" at the console.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Compile PDF tab **during** compilation and then click Reload in the menu that appears, and the Stop button should appear.

Right click on the Compile PDF tab **after** compilation and then click Reload as before, and the View Log, Output, and Issues buttons should appear.

(Found by trial and error.)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Have you let RStudio know? I posted a question on there and they got back right away saying it was a bug and they were looking into it. Let me uninstall and reinstall RStudio to see if it works for me then I can mark your answer correct potentially.

Comment: I tried it and it did work temporarily, but it reverts back. Here's the issue with RStudio https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115007977268-RStudio-1-0-143-Buttons-for-Stop-Output-Issues-are-hidden. My work around was to download the previous RStudio Version 0.99.903 and the buttons are consistent. I don't think downloading the previous version is actually an answer as it is currently a bug.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it reverts, and considered including that in my answer, but I thought it might be too much detail (this is my first answer, so still getting the hang). While it would be nice if it persisted, you can reload again every time you compile to get the buttons back. If the lack of persistence makes this not sufficiently helpful for you, then by all means don't accept my answer, and I hope someone comes along with a better fix, because that's all I've got. I found your question while googling to try and find out how to get the Stop button, and would have loved if it had had (cont)

Comment: (cont) an answer explaining how to get it to appear at all, which is why I decided to submit this answer when I found out how to get it myself by trial and error.

Comment: No, I haven't contacted RStudio. As far as I'm concerned, reloading every time might be a bit annoying but it works and I figured someone else would submit a bug report (or indeed probably already had). It's probably worth mentioning that my need was to stop the compilation, which isn't necessary very often. I don't use the View Log, Output or Issues buttons: if I run into TeX compilation problems I open the generated TeX file in an editor and try compiling again from there to see what the issue is. So it's less annoying for me to have to reload to see the buttons than I imagine it is for you.

Comment: No worries. I appreciate your input because if the previous version of RStudio were not available then I would be in a jam, and at least your answer provides some relief. Hopefully it gets sorted out, but for now, I am using an older version of RStudio which is working fine. They are available for download on the RStudio website (and all buttons appear) if that helps you. Thanks. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206569407-Older-Versions-of-RStudio

Answer (score 1):

This particular issue should also be resolved from v1.1.364 of RStudio, which (at the time of this post) is available as a [preview release](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/).

Comment: I've just upgraded to v1.0.153 and all the buttons are appearing as they should in that version too.